# How to get Appointment recurrence in XML format using EWS?

Tags: exchange-server, icalendar, exchangewebservices, appointment

I am working on Mail Application. I want to get Appointment details from Exchange Server Account using EWS. I use Scheduler control which get details of recurrence in XML format. I want to get details of Appointment in either XML or in String Format.

For Example, This is Gmail occurance detail

Test: Weekdays, Never End Meeting

Recurrence object details: "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR"

I use following method to get Appointment.

```
foreach (Appointment appointment in service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new ItemView(int.MaxValue)))
{
     appointment.Load();
}
```

Can anybody please suggest me appropriate way?